# Sqlite first use does not save record

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a problem with my sqlite.
when i install the app and database is empty. the first entry is never stored.
there is any way to solve this???

this is the code to insert data :

```
final ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
values.put("cod_comp",pub_cod_comp);
values.put("telefone_comp", pub_telf_comp);
values.put("morada_comp", pub_morada_comp);
values.put("porta_n_comp", pub_porta_comp);
values.put("cod_postal_comp", pub_cp_comp);
dataBase.insert("Comprador",values);´
```

this the insert in my class database:

```
public void insert(String table, ContentValues values) throws SQLException {
    mDataBase.insert(table, null, values);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your table creation script and columns names?

Comment: The table was not crested in code. Was in SQLite Devoleper.

Comment: here is a print of the report.

Comment: Sorry i am not being able to copy the report, because of the indentation.